# Error Handling Mechanism while Http Request (REST API) angular2

Tags: rest, http, service, angular

I am making some REST call (using HTTP request) in angular2.As depend on condition requests are of type GET,POST,PUT,DELETE.
Everything works fine for me i am using the below method to make request using seprate service file and class (component class) file.

### * service.ts

```
PostRequest(url,data){
this.headers = new Headers();
this.headers.append("Content-Type", 'application/json');

this.requestoptions = new RequestOptions({
    method: RequestMethod.Post,
    url: url,
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
    headers: this.headers
})

return this.http.request(new Request(this.requestoptions))
    .map((res: Response) => {
        if (res) {
            if(res.status == 201){ 
                return [{ status: res.status, json: res.json }]    
            }
            else if(res.status != 201){ 
                return [{ status: res.status, json: null }]
            }
        }
        // i want to handle error here but how i don't know
    }); 
}
```

- component_class.ts

```
this.base_path_service.PostRequest(url_postSection, data)
.subscribe(res=> {
   if (res[0].status == 201) {  //some stuff here..... }
});
```

Now come to question, my Question is

- How can i handle error occured in the http,
- i know `next,error,oncomplete` methods of subscribe but is it possible to handle the error at the time of mapping observable i.r
       return this.http.request(new Request(this.requestoptions))
        .map( //is it possible to handle error here instead at the time of subscribe)
- i want to get notify to user depends on status code(201,200,204 etc...), so i want to write code once i.e at the time of .map instead of
    writing code agagin and again at the time of subscribe

  if any another approach is good for error handling while HTTP please post it as answer with example.

Answer (score 3):

You can leverage the catch operator to handle errors:

```
return this.http.request(new Request(this.requestoptions))
    .map((res: Response) => {
        if (res) {
            if(res.status == 201){ 
                return [{ status: res.status, json: res.json }]    
            }
            else if(res.status != 201){ 
                return [{ status: res.status, json: null }]
            }
        }
    }).catch(error) => {
      // Do something
      // Observable.throw(new Error('some error');
    }); 
}
```

In fact when an error occurs, the registered callback un the map operator won't be called.

Comment: well i had tried as you post answer, but now angular throws error `Observable is not defined` , now if i handle this error in the subscribe's `err callback function` block  it handled it think but i want to handle the error in catch block only, i dont want to send reponse in subscribe block when error encounter what should i do ?

Comment: You need to import the `Observable` class: `import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';`. For your use case, don't throw from the observable class...

Comment: i have return the status of error from catch block to subscribe now getting error ` result.subscribe is not a function` from Rxjs

Comment: Found the error, whenever i return `error.status` angular throws error  named as `result.subscribe is not a function` but when i tried same using `observable.throw(new error(error.status))` it works fine, did't know the reasons why but thats occured. btw thanks for your time.

Comment: You should return an observable instead of a raw value: "Observable.of(error.status);". Great if you found the solution to your problem ;-)

Comment: is there anything wrong if i send raw data instead of sending Observable ?